¿Cómo reproducir código R y Python de notebook en Kaggle?
Cree un notebook en jupyter , ahi active el kernel para R y sin problemas puedo ir ejecutando las celdas tanto de python como de R en el mismo notebook, lo quiero compartir en kaggle , pero no encuentro una opción para alternar el kernel, ni me permite alternar entre lenguajes en el mismo notebook, los graficos los hice con R y dependen del código de las celdas de python. Por lo que me gustaría una opción parecida a la de jupyter.
